# Recursive Functions to generate a variable with no duplicate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using MongoDB + Express.

I have a post endpoint where the name field is randomly generated. I have everything working correctly besides when I find a duplicate name.

I want to check if the name field already exists in that database. If it does, then I want to regenerate the name field and if not, have it save the object to the database. This is where I'm at in my create method for the controller.

Also, if the name is duplicated, I want the random string to go up by one so the length in the randomly generate function goes from using 8 - 9

```
 create: (req, res, next) => {
    const defaultRandomNameLength = 8;
    const { title, desc, img } = req.body;
    let randomlength = 0;
    const randomNameLength = (randomlength) ? randomlength : defaultRandomNameLength;
    let name = randomstring.generate({ length: randomNameLength, charset: "alphabetic" });

    SpoofItem.findOne({name})
    .then((result) => {

      if (result) {

        res.send(`dup found: ${name}`)
        //create recursive function here 

      } else {
        const spoofer = new SpoofItem({ title, desc, img, name }); 
        spoofer.save().then((spoofItem) => {
          res.json(spoofItem);
        }).catch((err) => {
          return res.status(500).json({
            error: err
          })
        })
      }
    }).catch((err) => {
      return res.status(500).json({
        error: err
      })
    })
  },
```

Comment: Why would you need to go from 8 to 9? Bottom line is that at 8 positions there is of course only a finite number of combinations that can possibly be generated. Querying the database for an existing value does not necessarily mean those possible combinations are already used when a match is found. If you want a random token then you should really pick a length with sufficient possible values and stick to it. Or indeed even consider your use case and work out if something already guaranteed unique will suffice ( ie `ObjectId` ). Which is better than recursively querying when you can.

Comment: I totally get what you're saying and heavily contemplated this. The name var will be used for the end of the URL as well otherwise would use objectID. Although the chance of it happening probably wouldn't, I want to adjust for scalability in case that does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that I really agree it's the best handling of the problem, but as an academic exercise it's really just a matter of wrapping your name generation in a recursive function where you supply an incremented length parameter when a match was already found.

The only real constraint here is that your function should itself return a `Promise`, either as the result or by the recursive call to itself.

For the lazy, your implementation would be something like:

```
create: (req, res, next) => {
  const { title, desc, img } = req.body;

  // Recursive function definition
  function generateName(title, desc, img, randomLength) {
    const defaultLength = 8;

    randomLength = randomLength || defaultLength;

    let name = randomstring.generate({
      length: randomLength, charset: "alphabetic" });

    return SpoofItem.count({ name }).then(count => {
      if ( count > 0 ) {
        randomLength++;
        return generateName(title, desc, img, randomLength);
      } else {
        return SpoofItem.create({ title, desc, img, name });
      }
    });

  }

  generateName(title, desc, img).then(spoofItem => res.json(spoofItem))
    .catch(error => res.status(500).json({ error }));

}
```

Or perhaps a bit more modern using `async/await` keywords:

```
create: async (req, res, next) => {            // marked as async
  const { title, desc, img } = req.body;

  // Recursive function definition also marked as async
  async function generateName(title, desc, img, randomLength) {
    const defaultLength = 8;

    randomLength = randomLength || defaultLength;

    let name = randomstring.generate({
      length: randomLength, charset: "alphabetic" });

    let count = await SpoofItem.count({ name });
    if ( count > 0 ) {
      randomLength++;
      return generateName(title, desc, img, randomLength);
    } else {
      return SpoofItem.create({ title, desc, img, name });
    }

  }

  // try/catch instead of .catch()
  try { 
    let spoofItem = await generateName(title, desc, img);
    res.json(spoofItem);
  } catch(error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error });
  }
}
```

The big variation here is putting the repeating logic that would be present in recursion into the function that actually does the recursive calls itself. Note the "optional" parameter for `randomLength` since when it is not provided you would use a "default". Also the actual database write is moved inside this function, so other values that would be written are also passed into the function.

The basic idea being that given the arguments a name is generated and then you look in the database for that name. Using `.count()` is the most efficient way here since the value is available in the cursor stats without actually retrieving any data other than the stats themselves.

That operation returns a `Promise`, so you either continue with a `.then()` or `await` the result accordingly. Then it's just simple branching based on the "count" returned.

So either the value was found and the `randomLength` amount gets incremented and passed back into the recursive call, or the `.create()` method is called ( basically `new SpoofItem()` and `.save()` in one ) to actually write the "unique" value. Either way, a `Promise` is returned.

By the same case, the "wrapped" function is also awaited for resolution via either `.then()` or `await` as is appropriate. The `.catch()` or `catch` covers the possible errors.

Again, those "errors" probably "should" be delegated to the `next` handler instead, but that's not really the issue at hand here.

---

As a more complete demonstration, the following self contained listings in either form should demonstrate the string length being incremented, mostly due to an initial short length which is certain to attract duplicates:

Either marking the function with `async` and using `await` on the inner call:

```
const randomstring = require('randomstring'),
      mongoose = require('mongoose'),
      Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.set('debug',true);

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost/test',
      options = { useMongoClient: true };

const testSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
});

const Test = mongoose.model('Test', testSchema);

async function generateName(randomLength) {
  const defaultLength = 1;

  randomLength = randomLength || defaultLength;

  let name = randomstring.generate({
    length: randomLength, charset: "alphabetic" });

  let count = await Test.count({ name });

  if ( count > 0 ) {
    randomLength++;
    return generateName(randomLength);
  } else {
    return Test.create({ name });
  }

}

(async function() {

  try {

    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri,options);

    // Clear existing data
    await Test.remove();

    // Loop random generation
    for ( let x = 1; x <= 1000; x++ ) {
      await generateName();
    }

  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }

})();
```

Or with a traditional `.then()`:

```
const randomstring = require('randomstring'),
      mongoose = require('mongoose'),
      Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.set('debug',true);

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost/test',
      options = { useMongoClient: true };

const testSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
});

const Test = mongoose.model('Test', testSchema);

function generateName(randomLength) {
  const defaultLength = 1;

  randomLength = randomLength || defaultLength;

  let name = randomstring.generate({
    length: randomLength, charset: "alphabetic" });

  return Test.count({ name }).then( count => {

    if ( count > 0 ) {
      randomLength++;
      return generateName(randomLength);
    } else {
      return Test.create({ name });
    }

  });

}

(async function() {

  try {

    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri,options);

    // Clear existing data
    await Test.remove();

    // Loop random generation
    for ( let x = 1; x <= 1000; x++ ) {
      await generateName();
    }

  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }

})();
```

Either case generates 1000 "unique" random strings, where the number of elements will be pushed out to `3` given the collision possibilities on the supplied lengths.

Optionally add a "unique" constraint on the schema to "prove" that the values are in fact "unique", but that is basically the point of the `.count()` operation, so it's just additional "enforcement" that is not actually required when governed by the other existing logic.

Comment: Thank you for this. It's been really hard for me to wrap my head around recursive functions. I appreciate you explaining this out with code examples related to what I'm trying to solve.